# How to add automated lines to payment term line table

Tags: python, odoo-10

I want to create a method that adds automatically new lines in `account.invoice.line` table.The user should only enter the total amount of dues and fixed amount that should be paid per month. I created a new python file with this code:

```
class AccountPaymentTerm(models.Model):
_inherit = "account.payment.term"

    how_much = fields.Float()
    fixed_amount = fields.Float(default=100)
    invoice_date = fields.Date()

    @api.onchange('fixed_amount')
def automate_creation(self):
    terms = self.line_ids.browse([])
    self.nslices = int((self.how_much/self.fixed_amount))
    print(self.nslices)
    i = 0
    day = datetime.today().day
    month = datetime.today().month
    year = datetime.today().year
    nt_current_month = monthrange(year, month)[1]
    ndays = (nt_current_month - day)+1
    next_date = self.invoice_date
    print(next_date)
    #next_date = self.invoice_date + timedelta(days=ndays)
    while i<self.nslices:
        terms+=terms.new({'value': 'fixed',
                          'value_amount':self.fixed_amount,
                          'days':ndays,
                          'due_date':next_date,
                          'option':'day_after_invoice_date',
                          'payment_id':self._origin.id})
        i=i+1
        if month==12:
            month=1
            year=year+1
        else:month = month +1
        ndays = ndays + monthrange(year, month)[1]
        interval = timedelta(days=ndays)
        next_date = self.invoice_date
        next_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(time.strptime(next_date, "%Y-%m-%d")))
        next_date = next_date + interval
        date = next_date
        next_date=date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    terms+=terms.new({'value': 'balance',
                          'value_amount':0.0,
                          'days':ndays,
                          'due_date':next_date,
                          'option':'day_after_invoice_date',
                          'payment_id':self._origin.id})
    self.line_ids = terms

class AccountPaymentTermLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = "account.payment.term.line"
    due_date = fields.Date()
```

But when I change `fixed_amount` value. It generates the Payment Term lines without any value in `due_date` field. I can't see where my problem is.